# Connecting to windows azure with a VPN

Tags: azure, vpn

I am running a few machines and we services in Windows azure that I would like to lock off to the rest of the world because of the confidential data that is on there. I have a few small things that make it harder to get at, but I would like to setup a VPN to lock it down. If I set up a VPN service on one of the VM's would I then be able to latch onto the virtual network I have setup there? What is the process in setting this up?

Comment: Not a question for SO. Try [sf]

Answer (score 0):

If your cloud service is in a VNET you can create a VPN gateway and connect to it using either a [Site-to-Site VPN](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-site-to-site-create/) or a [Point-to-Site VPN](https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/vpn-gateway-point-to-site-create/). The former is IT focused, requiring VPN router configuration - the latter is developer focused, and requires minimal configuration. When using either form of VPN it is possible to take your cloud service completely off the internet for inbound traffic - outbound traffic can go out regardless of what endpoints you define for your VM.